# When converting my C++ program to Assembly in Visual Studio, there is over 1400 lines. When using godbolt.org, it is only 51 lines. What is different?

Tags: c++, assembly, godbolt

I have a simple program that asks for a number and gives the factorial of that number. I used godbolt.org to convert the C++ code to convert it into Assembly. I needed to download a Assembly file, but godbolt does not have an option to. I also found that the assembly is different when comparing them.
Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num, i;
    int product =1;
    cout<<"Enter a number:\n"<< endl;
    cin>>num;
    for(i=num;i>0; i--)
        product = product * i;
    cout<<"The factorial for " << num << "is: \n"<< product;
    return 1;
}
```

Assembly code from godbolt.org:

```
.LC0:
        .string "Enter a number:\n"
.LC1:
        .string "The factorial for "
.LC2:
        .string "is: \n"
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 1
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&))
        lea     rax, [rbp-12]
        mov     rsi, rax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt3cin
        call    std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator>>(int&)
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax
        jmp     .L2
.L3:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], eax
        sub     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
.L2:
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
        jg      .L3
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
        mov     rdx, rax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
        mov     esi, eax
        mov     rdi, rdx
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC2
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
        mov     rdx, rax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     esi, eax
        mov     rdi, rdx
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
        mov     eax, 1
        leave
        ret
```

Assembly code from Visual Studio:
The assembly code from Visual Studio is too long to include in the post.

I thought I could just do it in Visual Studio with the same results. To see the asm file in Visual Studio I right click my source file > properties > C/C++ > Output Files > Assembler Output, and then select "Assembly-Only Listing (/FA)". I then go to my project file and open the asm to see the assembly code. The assembly code in Visual Studio is significantly longer than on godbolt. Am I selecting the wrong file or property option?

Comment: Godbolt doesn't show library code (at least by default, not sure about an option to show it).

Comment: Afaik Compiler Explorer heavily filters the output to make it more readable. I would also be interested in an answer that explains how exactly the code is filtered.

Comment: You're looking at  GCC output on Godbolt, not MSVC.  godbolt.org has different compilers installed, including MSVC.  MSVC's asm output includes template functions that are never actually called, for some reason.  And yes, as @chrysante mentions, the Godbolt compiler explorer by default filters out "library functions", so your asm output isn't cluttered with templates for stuff like `std::vector::operator[` in a debug build where that doesn't inline.  (The code that calls functions like that is still nasty, though; normally enable some optimization.)

Comment: A comment on another question ([Very verbose ASM code of MSVC /Os vs GCC -O2 for simple template code](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/131611211)) mentions that most of the MSVC asm is initialization of iostream, which in GCC output is compiled into the shared library and not part of the compiler-generated asm.  (In real MSVC binary output, that might also be the case.  Still looking for a duplicate about MSVC output including unused functions.)

Comment: Oh, maybe I was mis-remembering, or there's a separate effect, that MSVC *does* generate more template instantiations and relies on the linker to remove unused ones.  Found an exact duplidate, [Why does the MSVC C++ compiler expand a simple Hello World into 4000 lines of assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61879225), which uses MSVC on Godbolt.org vs. GCC on Godbolt.org.

Comment: godbolt can show the full assembly, 30k lines for your program: https://godbolt.org/z/6Eb13voMx but its default filters reduce this to a mere 2k lines: https://godbolt.org/z/WMPxYcqcc